# how to reload $location.path() in parent window from within modal in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

*$location* object seems to be the modal one, not the parent one.
My modal performs an operation over a listing in the parent window, so when user clicks a button into the modal i want to close the modal (already accomplished) and reload the listing (parent) window.

Calling the controller of the parent window would perform a new listing so would be also nice.

Comment: You need to hook into the close event of that modal on your parent controller, and change the $location there. Hard to tell without knowing which modal you're using

Comment: Have you tried `$location.reload()` after click handler?